# On local storage save function, pass variables to MySQL db as well

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, local-storage

I have this script where each user is able to personalize each available widget (id, style, position, ...) and their changes are being saved to HTML5 local storage - but I also want to pass those variables to MySQL db, so if a person accesses site from a different browser they don't have to rearrange everything from scratch, but those previously set vars are pulled from MySQL db if local storage is empty.

I'm not sure how to pass these 3 vars to MySQL db from JS file on localstorage save.

I should call PHP query file from Ajax I guess, but not sure how.

```
//** SAVE SETTINGS FUNCTION **//        

function saveSettingsWidget(){  
    if(localStorage && o_localStorage){
        var storeSettings = [];

        obj.find(o_widgetClass).each(function(){
            var storeSettingsStr          = {};
            storeSettingsStr['id']        = $(this).attr('id');
            storeSettingsStr['style']     = $(this).attr('data-attstyle');
            storeSettingsStr['hidden']    = ($(this).is(':hidden') ? 1 : 0);

            storeSettings.push(storeSettingsStr);
        });

        var storeSettingsObj = JSON.stringify( {'widget':storeSettings} );

        /* Place it in the storage(only if needed) */
        if(getKeySettings != storeSettingsObj){
            localStorage.setItem(keySettings, storeSettingsObj); 
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

OK, so I've managed to call the PHP (with insert and update queries) with Ajax, all working fine, MySQL db updates all values.

Now, intention is to call those values if local storage is empty.

I have created a PHP query that outputs values in exact same way as local storage has them stored:

```
$query = "SELECT id , position , color , title , hidden , collapsed FROM mod_pos  ORDER BY `position` ASC";

if($result = mysql_query($query))
{
    // fetch data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $row_set[] = $row; 
    }

    // set the output
    $jsonsettings = json_encode($row_set);

} 
$json='{"widget":' .$jsonsettings. '}' ; 
echo $json;
```

so the output is

```
{"widget":[{"id":"widget1-42","position":"0","color":"default","title":"Title1","hidden":"0","collapsed":"0"},{"id":"widget5-42","position":"1","color":"default","title":"Title5","hidden":"1","collapsed":"0"}]}
```

NOW - If my local storage is empty I want these saved values parsed by I'm assuming:

```
var url = "url-to-php-file-with-json-output.php"
$.getJSON(url,function(json){          });
```

but where do I do that...

in JS file there is a section where keys are set:

```
if(localStorage && o_localStorage) // this is if localStorage is enabled and there are values in browser's local storage
{               
var keySettings    = 'widgets_settings_'+location.pathname+'_'+objId;
var getKeySettings = localStorage.getItem(keySettings);
}
```

should I put an

```
else { $.getJSON ...}
```

here and should I define keys differently
since by looking at:

```
var keySettings    = 'widgets_settings_'+location.pathname+'_'+objId;
```

that is the identifier for local storage - it supersedes the actual output, which is irrelevant for the new source of data, now being mysql output.

or should I skip that section and rather specify it here:

```
 if(localStorage && o_localStorage && getKeySettings){

var jsonSettings = JSON.parse(getKeySettings);
```

and how...

I know this must be a completely ridiculous Q for some, but I would really appreciate a bit more detailed help, if possible.

Thanks million

Answer (score -1):

Yes, AJAX.  If you're using a framework (jquery), there are a bunch of tutorials on the web.  Maybe start [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).